# how can I create QUrl from encoded url

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QString which contains encoded URL, that means, the url as you would insert it to browser, for example:

```
QString string = "http://domain.tld/index.php?some%20encoded&another%20encoded";
```

When I create QUrl like

```
QUrl(string);
```

it randomly decides what should be encoded and what shouldn't, in this case it leave "?" and "&" decoded, but AGAIN encode the percent symbol. So the target php application receive "some%20encoded" instead of "some encoded".

This seems to be some feature of QT when it automatically attempt to parse "and fix" url. This feature can be disabled by calling

```
QUrl(string, QUrl::StrictMode);
```

which works perfectly in qt 5+ but in qt 4, despite it compiles, it has same behaviour as if I didn't provide StrictMode parameter. How can I create url from string I encoded myself and which needs no further encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's you are looking for is

```
QUrl QUrl::fromEncoded (const QByteArray  &input ) [static]
```

[QUrl doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qurl.html)